# Set variable from Select Result

Tags: dbeaver

How to set Variable using Select Result

ej:
Set @Account = Select Account from att where name = 'william'

This command not run in script execution.

Comment: Please specify the DB that you are using (i.e. mssql)...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.